# How to record a refund in QuickBooks Online using the api?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I was looking through the API reference, and I didn't see anything that looked like the Refund Receipt used in QBO to represent a refunded transaction. Is it called something else in the api or is there a different way to record a refund? Will support for this become availbable in v3?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for credit memo entity in V2 and V3.For QBO V2, it is not supported.
For QBD V2, credit memo is supported:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy/qbd_v2/qbd_v2_reference

For QBD V3 services, it is supported:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy/qbd_v3/qbd_v3_reference/030_entity_services_reference

For QBO V3 services, it is supported.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services

Please note that v2 qbo, v2 and v3 qbd are deprecated.

Comment: These links are obsolete. Editing my ans above

Comment: Could you please include the relevant parts from these links so that if/when these links also become invalid, the answer is still relevant?

Comment: "the link will always work" says the person who just fixed broken links